How to show that counts are not associated with the different durations over which each count was taken?
Scientific Background
There is a publication[1] with associated data: Zenodo, GitHub. The Zenodo data is missing two columns, while the GitHub data is missing some rows.
The publication/data is from an experiment on the effects of microplastics on sand crabs. 64 crabs were kept in individual jars, of which 32 were treated with three microplastic fibers added to their water every four days, up to 71 days.
The number of microplastic fibers in (and I suppose also on) each crab was counted at the end (crabs that died before the 71 days were frozen). This was used as a fixed effect in a linear mixed effects model, and called the "number of fibers internalized".
The Scientific Issue
The name "number of fibers internalized" doesn't seem right. What if fibers were ingested and then expelled? A plot of survival time vs fiber counts doesn't show much of a relationship:

The Question
What is/are the way(s) to show that there is/isn't a significant association between counts and the different durations over which the counts accumulated?
My Attempt
The Model
I fit the following GLM in R (names modified from the Zenodo data, and txs = the treatment crabs half of the data):
glm(num_of_Yellow_fibers_ingested ~ log(num_of_days_alive) + 1, family = poisson(), data = txs)
which yielded with summary():



param
Estimate
Std. Error
z value
Pr(>|z|)




(Intercept)
0.87576
0.69172
1.266
0.205


log(num_of_days_alive)
-0.07686
0.18669
-0.412
0.681



which I interpret as "no, there isn't much of an association between counts and the different durations over which the counts accumulated", because of the small Estimate, relatively large Std. Error, and small Pr() for log(num_of_days_alive).
My Rationale
A poisson outcome sounded appropriate because it's count data. There is a max number of fibers, but I didn't have a better idea.
I suspect I could've just used lm(counts ~ time) with this data, looking at the above plot.
I used log(time) as a predictor because I read that doing so lets you combine data with different exposure durations, with the coefficient indicating the change in rate over time.
The associated algebra:
$$ y \sim Poisson(\lambda)$$
$$\lambda = \mu/\tau$$
$$log(\lambda) = log(\mu/\tau)$$
$$log(\lambda) = log(\mu) - log(\tau) = \alpha + \beta*x$$
$$log(\mu) = log(\tau) + \alpha + \beta*x$$
where $\mu$ = expected number of events and $\tau$ = time.
References
[1] "Effects of Environmentally-Relevant Concentrations of Microplastic Fibers on Pacific Mole Crab (Emerita analoga) Mortality and Reproduction." Horn DA; Granek EF; Steele CL. 2019.
